# How to pretend to press keys of my keyboard

Tags: c, windows

I'd like to make a program that presses keys of my keyboard, or I better say a program that tell computer keys are pressed (whereas they aren't), but I don't know which language is most suitable for that purpose. Maybe C? And if the most suitable language was C, what libraries or system call should I use?

My OS is Windows 7.

Comment: EDIT: My OS is Windows 7

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

On windows you can use the `keybd_event` function.

```
VOID WINAPI keybd_event(
  _In_  BYTE bVk,
  _In_  BYTE bScan,
  _In_  DWORD dwFlags,
  _In_  ULONG_PTR dwExtraInfo
);
```

It is defined in `windows.h`.

Example program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <windows.h>

/* Types the string @str on a virtual keyboard. */
void type_str(const char *str)
{
    char ch;
    int key;
    while ((ch = *str++)) {
        if (!isalpha(ch) && ch != ' ') {
            fprintf(stderr, "Cannot type '%c'!\n", ch);
            continue;
        }
        fprintf(stderr, "Typing '%c'.\n", ch);
        if (isupper(ch)) {
            key = ch; /* The keycode equals the character value for all
                         alphabetic characters and space. */
            keybd_event(VK_SHIFT, 0, 0, 0);

            /* 2nd arg: 0 means press the key. */
            keybd_event(key, 0, 0, 0);

            /* 2nd arg: KEYEVENTF_KEYUP means release the key. */
            keybd_event(key, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);

            keybd_event(VK_SHIFT, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
        } else {
            /* We need to use the uppercase character value. */
            key = toupper(ch);
            keybd_event(key, 0, 0, 0);
            keybd_event(key, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    puts("Waiting one second!");
    Sleep(1000); // Wait for user to open a text editor.
    type_str("Hello world");
    return 0;
}
```

This example can only print alphabetic characters and spaces. If you want to add more characters to the function, visit this link to find keycodes for other keys: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx

More documentation on the function can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646304(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: This is not appropriate advice, this function has been deprecated a while ago.  It has a severe usability problem, there is no way to discover that you are using the function incorrectly.  It doesn't have a BOOL return value.  Use SendInput() instead.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I didn't notice that. Unfortunately I don't know how to use `SendInput`. Feel free to post your own answer using it.

Comment: I have solved the problem with SendInput